# .gitattributes: does text=auto still uses core.autocrlf to detect EOL

Tags: git

With a `.gitattributes` entry

```
 * text=auto
```

what line separators are used when checking out the text files? The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-Settostringvalueauto) states:

> **Set to string value "auto"**
>
> When text is set to "auto", the path is marked for automatic end-of-line conversion. If Git decides that the content is text, its
>   line endings are converted to LF on checkin. When the file has been
>   committed with CRLF, no conversion is done.
>
> **Unspecified**
>
> If the text attribute is unspecified, Git uses the core.autocrlf configuration variable to determine if the file should be converted.

This sounds to me that in case of `text=auto` `core.autocrlf` does not matter. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This sounds to me that in case of `text=auto` [in `.gitattributes`, having] `core.autocrlf` [in the configuration] does not matter. Am I right?

Mostly.  [The `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) now says, for `core.autocrlf`:

> Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the `text` attribute to "auto" on all files and core.eol to "crlf". ... This variable can be set to *input*, in which case no output conversion is performed.

Confusingly, just a few lines earlier, the `git config` documetnation says, for `core.eol` itself:

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the `text` property set **when core.autocrlf is false** [and I tell you **nothing** about when it set to `true` or to `input`]...  See [gitattributes(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for more information on end-of-line conversion.

(boldface and bracketed text mine).  And yet, the description of `core.autocrlf` talks about effectively setting `core.eol`, so what *does* happen when `core.autocrlf` is either `true` or `input`, *and* `core.eol` is set to `crlf`?

If we turn to [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html), we find this phrase hidden away:

> To control what line ending style is used in the working directory, use the `eol` attribute for a single file and the `core.eol` configuration variable for all text files. Note that `core.autocrlf` overrides `core.eol`

So, if you *don't* set `core.autocrlf`, this *doesn't* override `core.eol` either.  This means that whatever *you* choose for `core.eol` applies as a default.  But if you *do* set `core.autocrlf`, whatever you choose for a `core.eol` setting gets *ignored!*

---

The actual source code inside Git is terribly twisty (and has undergone numerous changes over the years).  There are a few things that one can say that are true across all Git variants, though:

1. Conversions normally<sup>1</sup> occur in just two places: when a file is copied from the index to the work-tree (the "output" phase), or when a file is copied from the work-tree to the index (the "input" phase).  The output side copies happen during `git checkout` and `git checkout-index`, both of which copy files from the index to the work-tree.  The input side copies happen during `git add`, which copies files from the work-tree to the index.
2. A file considered to be "binary" does not get modified.  A file considered to be "text" is a candidate for modification.

So, `* text=auto` means that all files become candidates for modification, and `core.autocrlf` has the same effect.  But exactly what modification is applied?  That part is tricky.  Assuming the above quotes from the two different configuration documentation sections are correct for all versions of Git:

- If, for any particular *path*, you have a `.gitattributes` setting with a *specific* `eol=`, the `core.eol` setting does not matter.  But this is independent of whether you have a `.gitattributes` setting for `text=`.
- Therefore, wherever you forgot to also have a specific `eol=` settting, your effective `core.eol` setting controls what those conversions are.

Hence, since `core.autocrlf` can change the effective `core.eol` setting, *and* you can neglect to set a *specific* setting for some `text` file, having `core.autocrlf` set can be like changing your `core.eol` setting to `crlf`, *even if* you do already have `text=auto` set for all files.  (What precisely happens if you set `core.autocrlf` to `input` would require careful testing.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The word *normally* is here because this talks about where files get converted on the way in and out of Git.  For some operations, though, such as `git diff` against a work-tree, or `git merge` with "normalization" enabled, Git must do a "virtual check-in" or "virtual check-in and check-out", in which case Git does some extra converting.  This is, unfortunately, *why* the actual code inside Git is so terribly twisty.

Comment: I very much agree trying to piece together the overall behavior from the git documentation is confusing. I think a big part of the problem is that the documentation is split up between the different variables/settings, but all of those settings work together (or against each other). This is one area where a decisive official document on how end-of-lines work and all the settings that are involved would be great. Both the answer @torek gives here and the one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379316/ are really helpful in digesting it all.