# Git: autocrlf=true core.eol=native vs autocrlf=input

Tags: git, settings, line-endings

Can somebody explain what is the difference between settings:

```
core.autocrlf = true

core.eol = native
```

and

```
core.autocrlf = input
```

When we use both cases?

Answer (score 16):

> When [should] we use [either of these settings]?

My preference is *never*.  On the other hand, I also don't work on Windows. :-)  However, if you read through all of the text below, you will see that if I did, I'd still say "never".  (Even if you are sharing some upstream repository in which you're not allowed to create a `.gitattributes` file, you can use the per-repository `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file in your own clone.)

> [What's the difference?]

To get to the difference, we need to first note:

- What are conversions?  What conversions can Git do?
- When can Git do conversions?  When *will* Git do conversions?
- How does Git decide that a file is "text"?

#### Conversions, input and output: cleaning and smudging

The first part is pretty straightforward, although it presents its own stumbling block for newbies.  Git can do any conversions you want, because it has what Git calls *clean filters* and *smudge filters*.

A *clean filter* is a conversion you—yes, you!—can write for yourself, that Git will apply when you copy a file from the work-tree to the index using `git add` or equivalent.  That is, suppose you have a file checked out into your work-tree, and you edit it, or replace it entirely, or run some program over it that makes changes to it.  You probably want to commit the new version of that file.  So you must run `git add path` to copy the file from the work-tree, back into the index.  (Remember that Git makes new commits from whatever's in the *index*, not from what's in the work-tree.  This is why you keep having to `git add` your files all the time: Git doesn't automatically copy from work-tree to index.)

Whenever you run `git add file`, Git will "clean" the file on the way in.  That's an *input conversion*.

Conversely, you can write your own *smudge filter*, which is something you do to file data when it comes *out* of Git (out of the index, into your work-tree).  Since all files inside Git, including those in the index where they're ready to be copied into the *next* commit, are in some special, internal, Git-only format, every file *must* be converted into the normal format that all your regular computer programs can deal with.  Whenever you extract the file *to* the work-tree, Git will "smudge" (dirty up) the file on the way out.  That's an *output conversion*.

Git will occasionally do an input conversion without actually copying the file into the index: in particular, if you run a `git diff` that has to compare a work-tree file to an index or committed copy of the same file, the one that's *inside* the repository has already been "cleaned", while the one that's in the work-tree is all "smudged" and "dirty".  They can't be compared until they are both in the same state, so Git will "clean up" the work-tree one before doing the diff.

#### The built-in line-ending conversions

Git has two built-in conversions.  One is meant to be used when cleaning, i.e., when files get copied from the work-tree into Git (into the index).  This one replaces CRLF line endings with newline-only, Linux-style, line endings.  The other is meant to be used when smudging, i.e., when copying files out of Git.  This one replaces newline-only Linux-style line endings with ... well, *something*.

This "something" is where `core.eol` comes in.  You can have Git replace newlines with CRLF, which you might want if you're on Windows and you have programs that demand that lines end with CRLF, but you're also working with people who work on Linux which demands that lines end with LF-only newline style endings.

Or, you can have Git replace newlines with LF-only ... except that's not a *replacement*, because a newline *is* a line-feed "LF" character.  It's a bit silly to call this a replacement.

You can have Git choose the ending based on your system, so that one configuration, with `core.eol` set to `native`, works on *both* Linux *and* Windows.

Git is a little sneaky: when it is going to "replace" LF with LF (which isn't a replacement after all) it tends to do nothing—not even to inspect anything—and hence go faster.  It seems like you might never notice this, except that the `core.safecrlf` setting requires that Git inspect things.  This `safecrlf` thing involves some guessing, and is meant to be overprotective and get you to set `.gitattributes` settings if you're doing conversions at all, so that you don't damage any binary files.

#### Binary files: how does Git decide that a file is text?

Some files, like `.jpg` images for instance, are simply *not text* and should *never* have *any* of their data modified in "text-ish" ways.  They need to be manipulated with image-manipulation code, not with a text editor, or a clumsy tool line Git's built-in conversions.  Git therefore needs a way to distinguish *text* files, which should get these line-ending conversions applied, from *non-text* or *binary* files.

If you don't tell Git which files are which, it is going to have to guess.  The method Git uses to guess is *not* to look at the `.jpg` or `.txt` extension—this doesn't work on a file named `README`, for instance.  Instead, Git looks at the *data stored in the file*, and guesses based on whether it "looks text-ish" or "looks binary".

As you can imagine, this guessing game is not perfect.  It may work for you, but if it doesn't, you can and should *tell* Git which files are which.  You do this by creating a file named `.gitattributes`.  In `.gitattributes`, you can list particular file names like `README`, or path name patterns like `*.txt` and `*.jpg`, as being "definitely text" or "definitely binary".  You do this with `text` or `-text`.  You can also tell Git: *guess!*  You do this with `auto`:

```
*.txt   text
*.jpg   -text
guess   auto
```

***You should never use `auto` if you can help it.***

***You don't have to do this if you never have Git do any conversions.***  The point of telling Git which files are text and which are binary is to make sure that Git does the conversions correctly, and you only need to do this if you are doing conversions.  So if you avoid Windows, you don't have to create a `.gitattributes` and list your files.  It doesn't really hurt to create it anyway, but if you do create it, you should try to have it cover all your files, so that Git does not have to guess.

#### Now that we know all this, we can understand the documentation

With the above in mind, we can see what `core.autocrlf` does by consulting [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) and scrolling down to the `core.autocrlf` description:

> Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the `text`
>    attribute to "auto" on all files and core.eol to "crlf". Set to
>    true if you want to have `CRLF` line endings in your working
>    directory and the repository has LF line endings. This variable can
>    be set to *input*, in which case no output conversion is performed.

In other words, `core.autocrlf=true` is like using the `auto` setting on all files, which is something you should never do.  So you should never use this. :-)  It *can* work, but I would not recommend it: create a proper `.gitattributes` and list all your files there, so that you are not playing guessing games.  **Once your `.gitattributes` file lists everything, `core.autocrlf=true` has no effect, because the `.gitattributes` setting overrides it.**

Using `core.autocrlf=input` tells Git to do the same guessing, but also to do only *input conversions* (during the `git add` cleaning for instance).  I have no use for this setting myself, and cannot really imagine any situation in which it's a good idea.  Such a situation might exist, but if you're going to do conversions at all, you should specify them explicitly; and once you have specified them correctly in your `.gitattributes` file, it seems to make more sense to do conversions in both directions, so there's no reason to use `input`.

As for setting `core.eol` to `native`, the documentation claims that this is the default (and it seems like the best choice), so there is no reason to bother, other than to override someone other configuration file's poor choice of a non-default setting.

Answer (score 2):

Both Github documentation and the git bible https://git-scm.com/book recommend these settings:

- **Mac/Linux:** `git config --global core.autocrlf input`
- **Windows:** `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

See:

- [Github recommendation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)
- [Git SCM book, paragraph "Formatting and Whitespace"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

I have been working with these settings for 10+ years in mixed environments and never had a problem.

Comment: `I have been working with these settings for 10+ years in mixed environments and never had a problem.` - good for you then that your work experience is so limited. Try working with a system that actively expects explicitly LFs on a Windows machine (anything WSL'd, dockerized or `*n*x`-shell-based), and use your `autocrlf true` then. You'll gain an experience you probably didn't get during your last 10+ years. Hint: even simple shell scripts break on CRLF in shebang, and you'll have them stored (and processed) in your filesystem like that with that particular setting.