# WSL git EOL configuration ignoring gitattributes?

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows' Subsystem for Linux's git (version 2.17.1) to manage a repository on my Windows laptop, but it's giving me a headache with end-of-line settings.

### Context

From what I can understand about EOL management in git (correct me if/where I'm wrong), there's two key areas that manage this:

- `.gitconfig`, where `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol` set up the general policy
- `.gitattributes`, where I can specify per-path `eol` and `text` attributes.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277143/gitattributes-does-text-auto-still-uses-core-autocrlf-to-detect-eol?rq=1) I learned that setting `core.autocrlf = true` is equivalent to setting `core.eol = crlf` and adding the `text=auto` attribute to every file; and that the `eol=` attribute overrides the `core.eol` configuration.

With that, I set up a small test to find out what options I need.

### What I'm trying to obtain and what I tried

In my repository, I'll have some files used only on the Windows side, some used only on UNIX machines and the source that will be used by both.
To avoid headaches, I want to set all Windows-only files to **always** have CRLF EOL, while converting everything else to LF when committing.

To do that, I thought I'll set in `.gitattributes` the line `*.vcxproj eol=crlf text` and be done with it. For good measure, just to be on the safe side, I also thought of adding `*.sh eol=lf text`. Finally, I came up with a small test to see if it actually works (Spoiler: it doesn't).

### Test Setup

My directory tree looks as follows:

```
root_dir/
    - real.sh       (has LF EOL)
    - real.vcxproj  (has CRLF EOL)
    - fake.sh       (has CRLF EOL)
    - fake.vcxproj  (has LF EOL)
```

`real.*` files have the "correct" EOL for their type, `fake.*` have the other one. The aim it to check which files raise a `warning` when `git add`-ing them to the repository.

The `git config -l` shows:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

Ideally, if everything worked as I understood it, the "fake" files raise the warning being converted to the opposite type.

Instead, what happens is:

```
$ git add -A
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in fake.sh.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in real.vcxproj.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Trying to understand why this happens, it seems that the conversion picks up the `core.eol` configuration (which defaults to LF on a UNIX system) and ignores what I specify in `.gitattributes`.
To test this hypothesis, I set `core.eol = crlf`, reset the index and then `git add -A` again, this time obtaining:

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in fake.vcxproj.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in real.sh.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Hypothesis confirmed, headache increased. Why are my `eol=...` attributes ignored? Is there a way to configure the automatic conversion on a per-filetype basis? If so, how?

Comment: I've had issues with the "warning" messages being kind of bogus at times. But that should not affect the `real.*` files. It does look like your Git is not reading your `.gitattributes`, which is odd and broken.

Comment: Opened a WSL Github issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3348

Answer (score 0):

After further tests, it seems some invisible characters ended up in my `.gitattributes` file, breaking the `eol=...` attribute. Generating the file via `cat "..." > .gitattributes` fixed the problem.